# Is it possible to render a stretched UIImage in a Cocos2d sprite?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage

I'm able to create an image and add it as a UIImageView (the commented out line below).  The image then renders stretched.

When I place it in a sprite, it only renders the original non-stretched image, probably because the image view hasn't had a change to stretch the image since it hasn't been added to a view.

Is there a way that the image can be rendered as stretched without the image view, then import the CGImage into a sprite?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_cool_image_here.png"];
image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 25, 25)];
UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
view.image = image;

//[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:view];

CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:view.image.CGImage key:@"image"];
sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
sprite.position = ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );
[self addChild:sprite];
```

I know there are some Cocos2d classes for this, such as CCSpriteScale9 but I'm curious if there is a way to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
[sprite setScaleX: 320/sprite.contentSize.width scaleY: 50/sprite.contentSize.height];
```

(As far as I understand the question)

Comment: This only stretches the sprite.  I'm looking to stretch the stretchable portion of the sprite, similar to resizableImageWithCapInsets in the code above.

Comment: `CCScale9Sprite` in that case (https://github.com/YannickL/CCControlExtension/blob/master/CCControlExtension/CCControl/Utils/CCScale9Sprite.h). Sorry for misunderstanding the question.